# What programs/utilities exist to print to epub file?

Tags: printing, epub

Google Chrome, Microsoft Word, and Windows for that matter all have a "Printer" called "Print/Save to PDF." This permits one to print pages from any program to a PDF file. I have considered using this for saving of web pages. However, the resulting PDF files are only practical to view on a tablet or computer; not my smartphone, e-reader or other smaller devices.

As I am painfully aware that no adequate solutions exist for the conversion of PDF to EPUBm I was wondering if a similar "Printer" was is for EPUB. For example, I would open a page/document, click CTRL+P, select the printer "Print/Save to EPUB", type in the desired file name, hit "Save" and have an EPUB file.

I have tried to search for such programs, but the only results focus on printing an already-existing EPUB file to printed paper. Recommendations welcome.

Comment: [https://calibre-ebook.com/](Calibre), the eBook manager, does a fine job of PDF to ePub conversions. I've never seen a print to epub driver, but would be interested.

Comment: If you rename an `.epub` file to `.zip`, you will see that it just contains html/xml files. Html is designed to auto arrange the text-picture-flow, e.g. when the size of the browser/reader changes, but it is not good in making a pixel perfect layout. That's why I doubt that you will find a printer driver for epub.

Comment: I had the same problem with reading PDFs on a smaller device since PDF is geared towards printing on paper. I haven't found a good way to create epubs yet. I expected epub as one of the options under Word's Save As but alas. Luckely, I've discovered the android Xodo app that has a "Reading Mode" option which renders most PDFs quite nicely like an ereader.